# vim: Why does the sh colour scheme highlight `$(...)` as an error?

Tags: bash, shell, vim

For example:

[image]

I was under the impression that `$(...)` was recommended over ``` `` ``` because it's easier to nest.

Comment: re: removing the “vim” prefix from the question: I understand that some dislike this… But I strongly prefer it, so unless there is a published community guideline that I've missed, I'd rather it stay.

Comment: If you put `#!/bin/bash` at the top of the script, is it still highlighted as an error?

Comment: @Brandon: yes, I believe it does… Although now that I've set `g:is_posix` all my problems are solved.

Answer (score 15):

Because your .vimrc file does not contain

```
let g:is_posix = 1
```

See http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=552108

Answer (score 4):

You are correct that `$( )` is recommended over backticks as the latter has been depreciated.  You're also correct that `$( )` is POSIX shell.  However, to the best of my knowledge, `$( )` was added to the [POSIX spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_06_03) in 2004 and assuming you have the latest version of `vim`, it is quite likely that the `sh.vim` syntax highlight file has not been updated to reflect this change in the POSIX shell standard.